# Mobile Lookup service in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Is there any amazon aws service available for mobile number lookup for mobile validation?
Like twilio lookup service(Ref: https://www.twilio.com/lookup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least as of 2017-09-02, AWS does not offer a telephone number reverse lookup/validation service similar to the offering by [Twilio Lookup](https://www.twilio.com/lookup).

Incidentally and for what it's worth, the Twilio service looks excellent. (Disclaimer: I am a small Twilio customer, but have no other affiliation with the company.)

The price may seem relatively high, but based on my past experience in telecommunications, it seems *very* reasonable.  The is largely attributable to the fact that the telephone industry operates on very different models than business on the Internet.  Conventional voice carriers imagine that data like this is their proprietary data rather than the public information that it in fact is, and they do not make access to it available at no charge.  Sometimes, the charges and policies related to the data are quite unreasonable.

If you wanted to build something like this into an application, particularly with the thought of potentially using a future AWS service should one be introduced (or a service from another vendor), my thought would be to use API Gateway, Lambda, and DynamoDB to build an intermediate layer, first.  When your app makes a request, it hits API Gateway, which invokes Lambda, which queries DynamoDB to check for a stored result from a prior request.  If no result is found, or the age of the result exceeds a threshold you define, launch the external API query, store the result, and return it to the calling application.  Then, you can change the underlying service in the future without changes to the app itself, since the Lambda code or the API Gateway mapping templates could reconstruct the data into the form your application expects, regardless of the underlying service.  Or you could invoke Lambda directly.

Comment: Is there any low budget service is available to validate the mobile(only valid mobile or not) like numverify,edq...

Comment: I don't know.  We generally don't make recommendation of products, services, libraries, etc., here, so that wouldn't be a question to ask at SO.  Perhaps the best way of validating a mobile number is to text a code to it via SMS and require the user to provide the code back to you, to confirm.  Otherwise, you are only confirming that it is working a number, but not necessarily the correct number.  Users are sometimes bad about typing their own number correctly and transposed digits may still result in a valid (but wrong) number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I worked on an API for telephone number lookup. There are lots of APIs that are available through which you can get the details of the person with the help of their phone number and vice-versa. The most popular API for mobile phone number lookup are [Twillo](https://www.twilio.com/), [WhitePages](https://www.whitepages.com/), [Reverse Phone Lookup](https://www.reverseasia.com/), and many more.

As we all know reverse phone lookup service is some trustworthy services due to which we can't get it for free of cost. We will have to pay some amount for using these API. You can try anyone from these APIs.